# Renew a self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, cryptography, signature

Let's say I have a self-signed X.509 certificate:

```
file some.bin
some.bin: Certificate, Version=3, Serial=00ea5db390c4cc0de3, Issuer=Some Certificate, not-valid-before=2022-08-02 06:51:44 GMT, not-valid-after=2042-07-28 06:51:44 GMT, Subject=Some Certificate
```

Obviously it has a signature value:

```
openssl x509 -text -in some.bin -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            ea:5d:b3:90:c4:cc:0d:e3
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: CN = Some Issuer
            Not Before: Aug  2 06:51:44 2022 GMT
            Not After : Jul 28 06:51:44 2042 GMT
        Subject: CN = Some Certificate
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:56:98:eb:e0:96:9f:f5:2d:f0:99:2f:d8:6c:ae:
                    36:27:c0:a2:0c:95:9e:df:3a:fe:b6:57:69:bc:a6:
                    13:26:c4:e0:ca:58:fe:8b:19:d4:1c:d8:bf:cd:a4:
                    64:00:e6:50:02:af:c5:fc:f6:ba:f1:2b:f5:96:51:
                    99:40:ba:2c:33
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                9F:BD:59:32:3C:23:95:BE:9B:C3:4F:45:55:5A:97:C6:13:94:B3:09
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                9F:BD:59:32:3C:23:95:BE:9B:C3:4F:45:55:5A:97:C6:13:94:B3:09
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            1.2.3.1: critical
                ...
            1.2.3.101: critical
..`.H.e....... .....U...j.A.........1.._Y.f.L..
            1.2.3.102: critical
..`.H.e....... ................................
            1.2.3.103: critical
..`.H.e....... ..C.T...Ld..c;.t.D4...>L..fFY.;.
            1.2.3.104: critical
$....N.?.8.... .$.......*h...f....}
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Signature Value:
        30:44:02:20:0f:e3:9f:d7:cd:27:5a:58:53:dd:4c:49:3c:71:
        fe:ba:85:28:c2:11:50:ba:81:a2:96:36:d9:e9:82:fc:84:01:
        02:20:59:05:09:e1:88:cc:9f:07:18:71:d8:ab:7d:52:63:e9:
        cd:e4:e7:01:11:88:4b:28:0e:54:99:0e:45:08:19:c4
```

Now having the certificate and the private key it was signed with (since it was self-signed), I want to change one of the 256 bit hashes included in the cert, in this case for example the OID 1.2.3.103. I can change the 32 bytes, no problem but how do I recalculate the signature value using my private key? The best way would be to recreate the whole certificate. I guess this should be possible?

Comment: What 256-bit hash do you want to change? And more importantly, _why_? Also, 20 year validity on a certificate isn't exactly recommended.

Comment: @mtak Yeah you're right, that is not meant for production. I posted the whole certificate and adjusted the question. I want to change the hash in OID 1.2.3.103.

Comment: Do you have the original CSR that was used to create the certificate (if there was one), or the original openssl.cnf, or such? It would be _easiest_ to repeat the regular issuance process using the same keypair and the same (adjusted) data.

Comment: I do have access to the private key, actually all I need is the openssl command to update the signature value.

Comment: While being a interesting question, in terms of practicality I think recreating the CSR with the same values and signing it again is the easy way out. Updating fields in an existing cert and then signing it again is really outside of the usual x509 workflow. I'm sure it can be done, but I doubt OpenSSL does something like this. If you have a box of mathematicians and computer scientists laying around, let us know how it went :)